# Equality Constraints over Sets with Tree Automata

Tags: reference-request, automata-theory, sat, set-theory, program-analysis

Tree Automata can be used to model sets of values of a [Herbrand Universe](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerbrandUniverse.html), for example, to model possible values in a functional program.

Systems of subtype constraints over set expressions have decidable satisfiability, but this is EXPTIME complete, and NEXPTIME complete when projections are allowed in expressions. See [here](http://tata.gforge.inria.fr/) and [here](http://lara.epfl.ch/w/_media/sav10:pacholski-set-constraints.pdf).

I'm wondering, has the set constraints problem over equality constraints, instead of subset constraints, been studied? Clearly it's not a harder problem than with subsets, but is it easier? Are there simpler solutions than tree Automata for solving such systems?